# SQL normalization: Mathematical?

Tags: sql, database-normalization

I'm taking a class in database design. The curriculum focuses heavily on nomalization. The steps and methods speak for themselves, however I find the intuition aspect frustrating. Is there a mathematical way to handle data normalization, where one can assign the properties and crunch a mathematically certain conclusion?

Comment: I understand where you're coming from with the frustration aspect, but I'm not sure this question can be answered, as it currently is. Is there an example of one of the normalization exercises you can provide that illustrates the intuition issue you've mentioned, and a brief on what part you're finding difficult (and why)? Beyond that, remember that its all about dependencies, and the goal is ultimately reducing redundancy. If you can keep that in mind when approaching a solution, that may hopefully help.

Comment: In my experience normalization is definitely more an art than a science, because the needs of the development team and performance also need to be taken into account when performing this task. For example, let's say after you get your CS degree, you are an architect on a project, and you whip out your book on normalization, analyze your data model, and develop a perfect 500th normal form database. Your developer and potentially customers will be cursing your name because it is so difficult to develop in, and performance may suffer. The level of normalization in a real project can be un-optimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give another real world example in a discussion regarding addresses.

You are architect in charge of redesigning a legacy app with an old database that contains address information.
The DB currently has 1 field for all address information.

Our address looks something like this:

```
Address
___________________________________
Bob Robertson 123 Broad Way Springfield IL 62701
```

Unacceptable! Let's normalize this a bit to remove some of that redundancy, so in our second pass, we break it up into a few fields:

```
Address1        Address2        City          State   Zip
________        ________        ____          _____   ____
Bob Robertson   123 Broad Way   Springfield   IL      62701
```

Well, you say, there are multiple addresses within a state, so we need to break that out into a lookup table, and we can save tons of space on that city name, and there is a one to many relationship between streetname and all of the numbers that exist on that street.

We also need to represent the 9 digit zip codes, and one 5 digit zip code has multiple 4 digit suffixes, so that needs it's own table too in order to fully normalize this relationship, boy am I clever!

Also, we might have multiple robertsons, and multiple Bobs that we ship things to, so we need a cross reference lookup table for that as well.

At this point, our table may look like this:

```
FirstNameID     LastNameID    StreetID  StreetNum     CityID    StateProvinceID   ZipID   4DigitSuffix
__________      _________     ________  ___________   ______    _______________   _____   ___________
3452            1257          45        234           990       32                123     1234
```

If you presented this to most rational developers, requiring 6 or more joins just to get address information, you might get run out of town on a rail.
In many cases, there is an optimal middle ground that satisfies business needs and also speed/ease of development.

Comment: You are not doing any normalization here, nor are you reducing redundancy. Normalization does not introduce new columns. Multiple appearances of the same value happens with or without redundancy. (See answers of mine re normalization and/or redundancy.)